# Get size of a binary tree in O(log n)

Tags: java, data-structures, time-complexity, binary-tree, big-o

Full disclosure: **This is Homework**.

I'm asked to return the rank in a Binary Tree, and after some coding I got it to work.
But since my code doesn't get accepted, I noticed that the code should run in `O(log n)`

And the culprit that slowes this down is my size method:

```
public int size(Node node){
    if (node != null) return (size(node.left) + 1 + size(node.right));
    return 0;
}
```

Which I call to get the rank of all elements smaller than the one I need to look for.

Now, I googled and all, but apparentely it is not possible to get the size of a BT in log n time?

How would I need to do this then?

Comment: How could you possibly count something in fewer steps than there are items? It's like saying "count from 1 to 100 in increments of 1 in 50 steps".

Comment: You can't do that with an ordinary BST.  The google words you want are "order statistic tree"

Comment: Hmm, I never heard that term in the lecture. Even the excercise refers to Binary Trees. But thanks, I'll look into it!

Comment: Is this a regular binary tree? Or is there some ordering of the nodes that you didn't share, e.g. it's a BST? And when you alternately say "size" and "rank", what exactly are you looking to measure?

Comment: I assume it's a BST as left = smaller, right = bigger.  With size I mean nr of leaves. Rank is i. e. if we have leaves 1, 2 and 3, rank of leaf 2 would be 1 (Indexing at 0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a simple binary tree that only stores children, it isn't possible to get the size in O(log(n)) time since there are n nodes, and you must count every one of them. However, why restrict yourself to only having children? Like many data structures, you can store the size with the node:

```java
class Node {
    public Node left;
    public Node right;
    public int value;
    private int size; // initialize this to 1
}
```

Then, when inserting into the node, increment the size of every node you encounter:

```java
public void insert(int value) {
    // increment the size
    this.size++;
    if (value < this.value) {
        // obviously check for null as well and insert as appropriate
        this.left.insert(value);
    } else {
        this.right.insert(value);
    }
}
```

Now, you can get the size in O(1) time, since every node has it.

Comment: Oh, I'll defintely try this! I'll let you know

Comment: You have made some assumptions. First in your example, that the binary tree is sorted - he never said it was. Second, that insertion always happens at the root node. For your example, if insertion happens at any node except the root, the size will get screwed up because parent nodes won't be updated.

Comment: Ok, this is the correct approach. They want us to augment the Datastructure. I'll now need to find a way on how to implement this, thanks